# pytest can't find module for tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, intellij-idea, pytest

I have a structure like (not exact names)

```
 - my_project
   - app
     - repo
       - __init__.py
       - my_repo.py
     - services
       - __init__.py
       - my_service.py
     - utils
       - __init__.py
     - __init__.py
     - main.py
   - __init__.py
   - test_main.py
```

Previously I had a flat structure and my tests worked, now that I changed to this structure, every time I try to run `pytest`, I get the following error:

```
portError while importing test module '/Users/user/IdeaProjects/my-project/test_main.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test_main.py:3: in <module>
    from app.main import app
app/main.py:3: in <module>
    from repository.image_repository import ImageRepository
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'repository'
```

bear in mind that I can run this project normally without any problems, the problems happen when I try to run the tests.

The import section of my `test_main.py` file is:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from app.main import app
from app.services.image_storage import ImageStorage
from app.repository.image_repository import ImageRepository
```

and the import section of my `main.py` file is:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, HTTPException
from repository.image_repository import ImageRepository
from services.image_storage import ImageStorage
from utils import generate_filename, is_image

app = FastAPI()
image_repository = ImageRepository()
image_storage = ImageStorage()
```

Comment: Your imports don't match your project structure. You have an `__init__.py` in `my_project`, which means that `my_project` is a package. But you never import `my_project` anywhere - you always import `app`. Make up your mind: If you want `my_project` to be a package, change your imports to `from myproject.app import ...`. If not, delete `my_project/__init__.py`.

Comment: I just noticed a bunch of other imports are also incorrect. I'm surprised you say the code works if you execute it; as far as I can tell it should throw an ImportError. `import repository`, `import services` and `import utils` are all wrong. These are sub-modules of `app`, so the correct way to import them is like `import app.utils` (or `import my_project.app.utils`).

Comment: I thought that since those packages were at the same level of the `main.py` file, I would import them that way

Comment: @Aran-Fey if I add the `app.[module]` part, my tests work but my running application breaks. Could you give me a hand?

Comment: Not without more info. 1) What did you decide to do, add `my_project` to your imports or delete the `__init__.py`? 2) How are you running the code? `python my_project/main.py`? 3) How exactly does it fail?

Comment: Don't see why I would need `my_project` to have an `__init__.py`, the code is run through docker as this is a fastapi project and the entry point is `main.py`. As mentioned previously, depending on which way I go, either the tests or the code don't work.